# What version of redux/react-redux work with react v0.14.9 installed via bower?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, bower

I am trying to add in redux to an existing sailsjs v0.12 project without updating every package in the gigantic pile.  The current react stuff is loaded via bower and the .bower.json file for react is:

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "main": [
    "react.js",
    "react-dom.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/facebook/react-bower",
  "version": "0.14.9",
  "_release": "0.14.9",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v0.14.9",
    "commit": "81ae9f4ab02851be30ce2b1eef3dfd78d291cfc8"
  },
  "_source": "https://github.com/facebook/react-bower.git",
  "_target": "~0.14.7",
  "_originalSource": "react"
}
```

I am trying to figure out what versions of react-redux and redux I can load via bower to work with the existing react version and where to get them, it seems there are a bunch of different sources and builds -should I just install certain (but which?) versions via npm and copy them over to the bower_components folder? The project automatically loads everything under that folder.

Update:
We copied redux version 3.0.4(via cdnjs) and react-redux version 4.4.0 into the bower_components folder. In one of the jsx files at the top I include that stuff like so:

```
requirejs.config({
  urlArgs: "v=" + ssweb.buildNumber,
  paths: {
    'react': '/bower_components/react/react-with-addons.min',
    'reactdom': '/bower_components/react/react-dom.min',
    'label': '/js/shared/reactLabel',
    'moment': '/bower_components/moment/moment',
    'redux': '/bower_components/redux/index',
    'reactRedux': '/bower_components/react-redux/dist/react-redux.min',
    'rootReducer': '/js/reducers/rootReducer',
  },
   shim: {    
     'reactRedux': ["react", "redux"]
   }
});




require(['react', 'label', 'moment', 'reactdom', 'redux' ,'reactRedux','rootReducer'], 
  function (React, Label, moment, ReactDOM, Redux, ReactRedux, rootReducer) {

    var createStore = Redux.createStore;
    var con =  ReactRedux.connect;
    console.log("rootReducer ", rootReducer);
    const store = createStore(rootReducer);
    const Provider  = ReactRedux.Provider;
    console.log("Provider  ", Provider);
    console.log("store ",store);           
    console.log("con  ", con);
    console.log("rootReducer ", rootReducer);

    class PCycle extends React.Component {
       ...
       render(){ 
            const measUnit = this.state.measUnit;
            return (
                <Provider store={store}>...extra stuff</Provider>
            );
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        ReactDOM.render(<PCycle avariable={window.theVariable} />, document.getElementById('p_container') );
    });
});
```

And that seems to be a start as the redux objects get printed to the console.  Now I want to like redux to my components.  In the code I have seen in an example react/redux project (by net ninja on youtube) using ES6 it looks like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps)=>{
  let id = parseInt(ownProps.match.params.post_id);
  return{
    post: state.posts.find(item => item.id === id)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
  return {
    deletePost: (id) => {
      return dispatch(deletePost(id))
    }
  } 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

So my question now is: how do I do that last part in my code in which I do not import things but used self calling functions contained in other self calling functions.

I have a .ejs page on which 5 different components - each made like the above PCycle.jsx above - coexist and I want them to share the same redux store so an update in one component can affect the state of another.  They are included on the .ejs page with script tags.